# Finding $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How to get value of $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$?

My solution so far is to take logarithm, split logarithm as row and sum column-vise:
$$\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}} = L$$
$$\ln(L)=\frac{1}{2}\ln1+\frac{1}{4}\ln2+\frac{1}{8}\ln3+\frac{1}{16}\ln4+\cdots$$
Using $$\ln(x+1)=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+\cdots$$
I get:
$$\ln(L)=\frac{1}{2}0-\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{4}}{4}+\cdots$$
$$+\frac{1}{4}1-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{4}}{4}+\cdots$$
$$+\frac{1}{8}2-\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{4}}{4}+\cdots$$
summing by columns i get:
$$ =(\frac{1}{2}0+\frac{1}{4}1+\frac{1}{8}2+\frac{1}{16}3+\cdots)-(\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{16}\frac{3^{2}}{2}+\cdots)+$$
$$+(\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{3}}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{3}}{3}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{3}}{3}+\frac{1}{16}\frac{3^{3}}{3}+\cdots)-(\frac{1}{2}\frac{0^{4}}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1^{4}}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{2^{4}}{8}+\frac{1}{16}\frac{3^{4}}{4}+\cdots)+\cdots$$

The "only" thing left is how to figure out these summs in each bracket.
Any idea hot to do that, or you may suggest another solution? Best regards.

Comment: okay, they just use polylog function for that, can it not be solver further to primitive functions?

Comment: You skipped a step.  Before you can set the limit of the sequence to $L$, you have to first prove that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Why do you put "only" in quotes?  It's not the only thing left to do.  You have to prove that the sequence converges.  There's nothing "quote unquote"/ironic/euphemistic or colloquial about it.